# Regex match without specific word

Tags: regex, typescript

I'm looking for regex that matches only the first occurrence of the expression.

An expression: [B]text[/B], And I have regex for that

```
\[[B]]([a-z0-9 ./,<>()!@#$%^&*+=;:'"\[\]\\|\t\n-]*)\[\/[B]]
```

But that expression may occurs few times, 
for example:
[B]test1[/B]
[B]test2[/B]

When that happens it looks like that:
test1[/B]
[B]test2

Instead of just test1 and test2
So I'm looking for some way to stop searching when it finds [/B], I know I allowed regex searching for "][/" but I want it not allowed when it's an expression "[\B]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\[B\](.*?)\[\/B\]
```

Here is [snippet](https://regex101.com/r/aelKWU/2). Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted :)